# Full parser examples with parsec?

Tags: haskell, parsec

I'm trying to make a parser for a simple functional language, a bit like Caml, but I seem to be stuck with the simplest things.

So I'd like to know if there are some more complete examples of `parsec` parsers, something that goes beyond "this is how you parse 2 + 3". Especially function calls in terms and suchlike.

And I've read "Write you a Scheme", but the syntax of scheme is quite simple and not really helping for learning.

The most problems I have is how to use `try`, `<|>` and `choice` properly, because I really don't get why parsec never seems to parse `a(6)` as a function call using this parser:

```
expr = choice [number, call, ident]

number = liftM Number float <?> "Number"

ident = liftM Identifier identifier <?> "Identifier"

call = do
    name <- identifier
    args <- parens $ commaSep expr
    return $ FuncCall name args
    <?> "Function call"
```

**EDIT** Added some code for completion, though this is actually not the thing I asked:

`AST.hs`

```
module AST where

data AST
    = Number Double
    | Identifier String
    | Operation BinOp AST AST
    | FuncCall String [AST]
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data BinOp = Plus | Minus | Mul | Div
    deriving (Show, Eq, Enum)
```

`Lexer.hs`

```
module Lexer (
            identifier, reserved, operator, reservedOp, charLiteral, stringLiteral,
            natural, integer, float, naturalOrFloat, decimal, hexadecimal, octal,
            symbol, lexeme, whiteSpace, parens, braces, angles, brackets, semi,
            comma, colon, dot, semiSep, semiSep1, commaSep, commaSep1
    ) where

import Text.Parsec
import qualified Text.Parsec.Token as P
import Text.Parsec.Language (haskellStyle)

lexer = P.makeTokenParser haskellStyle

identifier = P.identifier lexer
reserved = P.reserved lexer
operator = P.operator lexer
reservedOp = P.reservedOp lexer
charLiteral = P.charLiteral lexer
stringLiteral = P.stringLiteral lexer
natural = P.natural lexer
integer = P.integer lexer
float = P.float lexer
naturalOrFloat = P.naturalOrFloat lexer
decimal = P.decimal lexer
hexadecimal = P.hexadecimal lexer
octal = P.octal lexer
symbol = P.symbol lexer
lexeme = P.lexeme lexer
whiteSpace = P.whiteSpace lexer
parens = P.parens lexer
braces = P.braces lexer
angles = P.angles lexer
brackets = P.brackets lexer
semi = P.semi lexer
comma = P.comma lexer
colon = P.colon lexer
dot = P.dot lexer
semiSep = P.semiSep lexer
semiSep1 = P.semiSep1 lexer
commaSep = P.commaSep lexer
commaSep1 = P.commaSep1 lexer
```

`Parser.hs`

```
module Parser where

import Control.Monad (liftM)
import Text.Parsec
import Text.Parsec.String (Parser)
import Lexer
import AST

expr = number <|> callOrIdent

number = liftM Number float <?> "Number"

callOrIdent = do
    name <- identifier
    liftM (FuncCall name) (parens $ commaSep expr) <|> return (Identifier name)
```

Comment: The specific question should be easy to answer, but I'd prefer to try with a full, compilable code sample demonstrating your problem... could you provide one?

Comment: I do note, however, that you don't use `try` anywhere. In your minimal example, I'm not sure if it matters, but in any larger sample it certainly would.

Comment: Trying to provide my whole program so far.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Hmm,

```
*Expr> parse expr "" "a(6)"
Right (FuncCall "a" [Number 6.0])
```

that part works for me after filling out the missing pieces.

**Edit:** I filled out the missing pieces by writing my own `float` parser, which could parse integer literals. The `float` parser from `Text.Parsec.Token` on the other hand, only parses literals with a fraction part or an exponent, so it failed parsing the "6".

However,

```
*Expr> parse expr "" "variable"
Left (line 1, column 9):
unexpected end of input
expecting "("
```

when call fails after having parsed an identifier, that part of the input is consumed, hence ident isn't tried, and the overall parse fails. You can a) make it `try call` in the choice list of `expr`, so that call fails without consuming input, or b) write a parser callOrIdent to use in `expr`, e.g.

```
callOrIdent = do
    name <- identifier
    liftM (FuncCall name) (parens $ commaSep expr) <|> return (Identifier name)
```

which avoids `try` and thus may perform better.

Comment: I use the lexer functions of `Text.Parsec.Token` for `identifier`, etc. For some reason, I get entirely different parsing results for the code you give me.

Comment: @Scán ah, the `float` parser of `Token` doesn't parse integer literals, you'd have to write `a(6.0)` or similar. But apart from that, it behaves like the above, more or less.

Comment: ... I feel dumb now. Thanks! (I'd still wish for those full examples)

Comment: @LambdaDusk Why is in this example always an empty "" preceding the actual input text?

Comment: @JFritsch That's the source name. If you have a parse error, and the source name is not empty, it's reported, so you get e.g. a parse error reported as `Left "Somefile.csv" (line 14, column 5): unexpected "1" expecting letter or ","`. With an empty source name, that is omitted from the report.

Comment: How can you allow only (pre)defined function call names?

Comment: You mean the parser should only accept certain names and fail for others? You can parse the name, and look it up in a set of allowed names (maintained as part of the state, for example), rejecting it if it is not found. Or, if the allowed names are known when writing the code, `choice [try $ string functionName | functionName <- allowedNames]` would be simpler.

Comment: @JFritsch You can define them as `reservedNames` in the [lexer](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/parsec/3.1.2/doc/html/Text-Parsec-Token.html) and then parse them using `reserved`. But that would mean you have to write a parsing code for every single of them, like you do for `if` and `for`.

Comment: Why does data Resname mine | alsomine | yours ... and have data AST | FuncCall Resname [AST] not do this job?

Comment: @JFritsch (Aside: The value constructors need start with an upper case letter.) You'd still need to write a parser for `Resname`, one string for every constructor. That wouldn't really simplify things versus using `String` for the function names.

Answer (score 2):

I wrote up a series of examples on how to parse Roman Numerals with parsec. It's pretty basic but you or other newcomers may find it useful:

https://github.com/russell91/roman